# Increment conditional formatting in excel

Tags: excel

I'm on Excel 2013.

I am trying to copy paste a conditional formating with a formula and I want when I copy the formula for example from A1 to A2 it increments also the cell number in the formula.

The formula in the conditional formating of A1 is :

```
 ="VLOOKUP($H1;'sheet'!$Y:$AE;7;FALSE)=$I1"
```

When I copy that in cell A2 I want the $H1 to be $H2 and the $I1 to be $I2.

I have tried to use the format painter of excel but it doesn't work.

Comment: change the `Applies to:` to the range you want.  Excel will increment as needed.

Comment: I didn't understand, can you give me an example please

Comment: if you click on A1 and click on Manage Rules in Conditional formatting there is a box for each rule that states `Applies to:` In that box change the range from `$A$1` to the full range to which you want to apply the rule.

Comment: Oh yeah ok but the cells in the vlookup formula don't increment it stays $H1 and $I1

Comment: The formula will always refer to the upper row of the applies to area.  Excel does the iteration in the back.

Answer (score 0):

The dollar sign is an absolute reference. It stops the default increment behavior. If you want the increment back just remove the dollar sign.

```
="VLOOKUP(H1;'sheet'!$Y:$AE;7;FALSE)=I1"
```

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2011/08/17/making-sense-of-dollar-signs-in-excel/